# Landscape - Postgresql database fill up storage

Tags: postgresql, landscape

Is there a way to limit database size or to erase landscape events?

If not, I suppose that I will have to extend the filesystem ?

```
root@prod-lds-db:~# du -shc /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/*
12G     /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/base
1,6M    /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/global
7,9M    /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_clog
28K     /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_multixact
12K     /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_notify
4,0K    /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_serial
240K    /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_stat_tmp
176K    /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_subtrans
4,0K    /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_tblspc
4,0K    /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_twophase
4,0K    /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/PG_VERSION
129M    /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_xlog
4,0K    /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/postmaster.opts
4,0K    /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/postmaster.pid
0       /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/server.crt
0       /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/server.key
12G     total
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple methods to limit physical database size. There is however a way to maintain one database on several disks (partitions).

You can create tablespaces, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE extra_space LOCATION '/extra/space';
```

(note, that the owner of '/extra/space' should be the same as of the default database directory, typically `postgres`).

You can create new objects (tables, indexes) in non-default location:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (id int, val text) TABLESPACE extra_space;
```

You can even move existing objects to non-default tablespace:

```
ALTER TABLE old_table SET TABLESPACE extra_space;
```

Read about tablespaces in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html).